# Unity3D: Extract Textures from FBX via C# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, textures, fbx, unity3d-editor

I am struggling to find a way to extract textures from an FBX model in Unity via script. Unity has a hidden method to extract materials [here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/Prefabs/PrefabUtility.cs), but cannot find a method to extract textures even in their own github.

i even tried to use the same approach to load Texture2D-s from the asset file like so:

```cs
    IEnumerable<Object> enumerable = from x in AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetsAtPath(assetPath)
                                                 where x.GetType() == typeof(Texture2D)
                                                 select x;
```

but to no avail.
Can anyone help? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`ModelImporter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ModelImporter.ExtractTextures.html):

```
var tex = AssetImporter.GetAtPath(pathToFbx) as ModelImporter;
tex.ExtractTextures(destinationPath);
```